# How to test PDF generated with PDFbox

Tags: java, automated-tests, pdfbox

I write a class that read pdf template and add some lines like:

```
List<PdfTextLine> textLines = pdfBankActPage.getTextLines();
    if (textLines != null) {
        for (PdfTextLine textLine : textLines) {
            contentStream.setFont(cyrillicFont, textLine.getFontSize());
            contentStream.beginText();
            contentStream.newLineAtOffset(textLine.getOffsetX(), textLine.getOffsetY());
                        contentStream.showText(textLine.getText());
            contentStream.endText();
        }
    }
```

My util class to store one-line info:

```
public class PdfTextLine {

    private Integer offsetX;
    private Integer offsetY;
    private String text;
    private Integer fontSize;
```

What is common approach how to test, that PDF was generated correct?

Comment: What kind of test are you after? A test of your program itself testing its outputs before sending? A unit test? Some blackbox test? Some other test type? And what do you want to test? The exact appearance? Merely the text content independent from its exact positioning and style? Something else?

Comment: @mkl I want to send piece of data, that splits by page and check that all parts are in right place with right data

Comment: Yes, but what kind of *test* are you after? Have a look at the questions in my original comment to get an idea what I mean.

Comment: You could run PDFStripperByArea to be sure that a text is at a specific place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question is lacking detail it is difficult to answer.
There are different possibilities to verify that your content was added:

1. Extract the text from the PDF and check whether your text is in there

   ```
   PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
   stripper.setStartPage(pageNumber);
   stripper.setEndPage(pageNumber);
   stripper.setAddMoreFormatting(false);
   String text = stripper.getText(this.document);
   ```
2. Use a library like [pdfcompare](https://github.com/red6/pdfcompare) (which itself uses Pdfbox) to compare the pdf visually...